# How to refresh an entity in a Future?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I am not really sure where my problem lies, as I am experimenting in two areas that I don't have much experience with: JPA and Futures (using Play! Framework's Jobs and Promises).

I have the following bit of code, which I want to return a Meeting object, when one of the fields of this object has been given a value, by another thread from another HTTP request.  Here is what I have:

```
    Promise<Meeting> meetingPromise = new Job<Meeting> () {
        @Override
        public Meeting doJobWithResult() throws Exception {
            Meeting meeting = Meeting.findById(id);
            while (meeting.bbbMeetingId == null) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                meeting = meeting.refresh();       // I tried each of these
                meeting = meeting.merge();      // lines but to no avail; I
                meeting = Meeting.findById(id); // get the same result
            }
            return meeting;
        }
    }.now();
    Meeting meeting = await(meetingPromise);
```

As I note in the comments, there are three lines in there, any one of which I think should allow me to refresh the contents of my object from the database.  From the debugger, it seems that the many-to-one relationships are refreshed by these calls, but the single values are not.

My `Meeting` object extends Play! Framework's Model, and for convenience, here is the `refresh` method:

```
/**
 * Refresh the entity state.
 */
public <T extends JPABase> T refresh() {
    em().refresh(this);
    return (T) this;
}
```

and the `merge` method:

```
/**
 * Merge this object to obtain a managed entity (usefull when the object comes from the Cache).
 */
public <T extends JPABase> T merge() {
    return (T) em().merge(this);
}
```

So, how can I refresh my model from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ended up cross-posting this question on the [play-framework](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/QRYlao7axtg/discussion) group, and I got an answer there.  So, for the discussion, check out that thread.

In the interest of having the answer come up in a web search to anyone who has this problem in the future, here is what the code snippet that I pasted earlier looks like:

```
Promise<Meeting> meetingPromise = new Job<Meeting> () {         
    @Override
    public Meeting doJobWithResult() throws Exception {
        Meeting meeting = Meeting.findById(id);
        while (meeting.bbbMeetingId == null) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (JPA.isInsideTransaction()) {
                JPAPlugin.closeTx(false);
            }
            JPAPlugin.startTx(true);
            meeting = Meeting.findById(id);
            JPAPlugin.closeTx(false);
        }
        return meeting;
    }
}.now();
Meeting meeting = await(meetingPromise);
```

I am not using the @NoTransaction annotation, because that messes up some other code that checks if the request is coming from a valid user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it but JPA transactions are managed automatically by Play in the request/controller context (the JPAPlugin opens a transaction before invocation and closes it after invocation).
But I'm not sure at all what happens within jobs and I don't think transactions are auto-managed (or it's a feature I don't know). So, is your entity attached to an entitymanager or still transient? Is there a transaction somewhere? I don't really know but it may explain some weird behavior if not...

Comment: I believe my entity is associated with an entity manager, since I retrieved it in the first place via `findById`.  However, I could be missing something.  Is there a way to tell, using the debugger or some other means?

Comment: JPA should be able to retrieve an entity even without an opened transaction and put it into its cache as an attached entity. But then if you want to modify, when is it committed??? moreover, what happens with relations??? I don't really know... JPA & hibernate become black boxes in these cases IMO and I don't know any way to analyze with the debugger (I may be ignorant :))... IMO, analyzing the play code and what happens is the best solution.